# asp.net mvc/web api replay attack remediation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I'm trying to do remediation for **asp.net mvc/web api auth cookie replay attack**. We have a web farm so storing token/state in session doesn't work for me.

I know I can go ahead and store tokens/flag for logged in/out and hit the DB with every request - does anyone know of a filter or something similar that has already been written and battle tested that I could look into? We are already using SSL and we use application cookie auth (similar but not forms auth).

Comment: I am not aware of any bullet proof off-the-shelf solution for this, but I once tackled this problem using sticky sessions and a custom HTTP module (aspnet): for each request a new session Id was created after verifying the existing session Id. This way the session cookie is only valid a very limited time

Comment: @LennartStoop sticky sessions isn't an option for us. we have a couple web servers and api servers.